# Javascript in react function when component is mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had my keypad working but now im implementing redux for the state handling. My old version was working as a class component and the javascript function was called on componentDidMount. This is not an option now anymore since i need to convert it to a function now in order to make it work with redux its dispatch. I tried putting the javascript under the return and calling it as a seperate function both didnt do anything. It there a way to do this?

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../style/App.scss';
import $ from "jquery";
import { UPDATE_GAME_STATE } from '../../actions'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

function Keypad(){
  init_keypad();
  return(
  <div className="keypad_wrapper">
    <div className="screen"></div>
    <div className="error notification">ERROR</div>
    <div className="success notification">SUCCESS</div>

    <div className="key">1</div>
    <div className="key">2</div>
    <div className="key">3</div>
    <div className="key">4</div>
    <div className="key">5</div>
    <div className="key">6</div>
    <div className="key">7</div>
    <div className="key">8</div>
    <div className="key">9</div>
    <div className="key last">0</div>
  </div>
);
}
export default Keypad;


function init_keypad(){
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  window.tries = 0;
  $(".key").click(function(){
    var n = $(this).html();
    $('.screen').append( n );
    window.tries++;
    // if 4 digits are entered check if its correct
    if (window.tries >= 4){
      var w = $('.screen').html();
      if (w == 1234){
        $('.success').show().delay(5000).queue(function(n) {
          $('.success').hide(); n();
          dispatch(UPDATE_GAME_STATE('playing'));
        });
      }
      else{
        $('.error').show().delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
          $('.error').hide(); n();
        });
      }
      $('.screen').html('');
      window.tries = 0;
    }
  });
}
```

THe error message is now this:

> React Hook "useDispatch" is called in function "init_keypad" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to use `useDispatch` in the React component instead of a normal function which in this case is `Keypad`

You need to wrap it inside useEffect as it's equivalent to componentDidMount in class component

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function Keypad(){
   useEffect(() => {
      init_keypad();
   }, []);

   return (
    ...
   );
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats all i needed!

Answer (score 0):

you need to used hooks in react component, which is not happening in your case while using useDispatch, so here you can do that in two ways make **`init_keypad`** as react functional component and then use `useDispatch` or rather simply pass the `useDipatch` from **`Keypad`**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../style/App.scss';
import $ from "jquery";
import { UPDATE_GAME_STATE } from '../../actions'
import { useDispatch, useEffect } from 'react-redux';

function Keypad(){
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
   useEffect(() => {
     init_keypad(dispatch);
   }, []);      
return(
  <div className="keypad_wrapper">
    <div className="screen"></div>
    <div className="error notification">ERROR</div>
    <div className="success notification">SUCCESS</div>

    <div className="key">1</div>
    <div className="key">2</div>
    <div className="key">3</div>
    <div className="key">4</div>
    <div className="key">5</div>
    <div className="key">6</div>
    <div className="key">7</div>
    <div className="key">8</div>
    <div className="key">9</div>
    <div className="key last">0</div>
  </div>
);
}
export default Keypad;


function init_keypad(dispatch){
  window.tries = 0;
  $(".key").click(function(){
    var n = $(this).html();
    $('.screen').append( n );
    window.tries++;
    // if 4 digits are entered check if its correct
    if (window.tries >= 4){
      var w = $('.screen').html();
      if (w == 1234){
        $('.success').show().delay(5000).queue(function(n) {
          $('.success').hide(); n();
          dispatch(UPDATE_GAME_STATE('playing'));
        });
      }
      else{
        $('.error').show().delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
          $('.error').hide(); n();
        });
      }
      $('.screen').html('');
      window.tries = 0;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use "useEffect" hook to use it as componentDidMount equivalent and avoid using window object to keep track of counts, instead use "useRef" hook as shown below

```
    import React from 'react';
    import '../../style/App.scss';
    import $ from "jquery";
    import { UPDATE_GAME_STATE } from '../../actions'
    import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

    function Keypad() {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const tries = React.useRef(0);

        React.useEffect(() => {
            $(".key").click(function () {
                var n = $(this).html();
                $('.screen').append(n);
                tries.current++;
                // if 4 digits are entered check if its correct
                if (tries.current >= 4) {
                    var w = $('.screen').html();
                    if (w == 1234) {
                        $('.success').show().delay(5000).queue(function (n) {
                            $('.success').hide(); n();
                            dispatch(UPDATE_GAME_STATE('playing'));
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.error').show().delay(1000).queue(function (n) {
                            $('.error').hide(); n();
                        });
                    }
                    $('.screen').html('');
                    tries.current = 0;
                }
            });
        }, []);

        return (
            <div className="keypad_wrapper">
                <div className="screen"></div>
                <div className="error notification">ERROR</div>
                <div className="success notification">SUCCESS</div>

                <div className="key">1</div>
                <div className="key">2</div>
                <div className="key">3</div>
                <div className="key">4</div>
                <div className="key">5</div>
                <div className="key">6</div>
                <div className="key">7</div>
                <div className="key">8</div>
                <div className="key">9</div>
                <div className="key last">0</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    export default Keypad;
```

However, I would also like to suggest you not to use jQuery along with ReactJs, as main purpose of using ReactJs is lost as you directly manipulate/play with DOM objects using libraries such as jQuery.

And it's a bad practice use jQuery along with RaectJs because React uses a concept called a Virtual DOM instead of a actual DOM. And React isn't aware of the changes made outside of this Virtual DOM. When you use jQuery or any other library that manipulates the actual DOM, there are chances that your application might go out of sync.

If you want to use jQuery for AJAX purposes, you can just use a library specifically made for AJAX, like Axios or the native Fetch API.

**And also do not forget to remove event listener on unmount, for this you could return an function in useEffect hook which will behave as componentWillUnmount method**